# Modelling adwords clicks with Bayesian Stats

Tags: bayesian, references, marketing

How can I use bayesian statistics for adwords clicks modelling? Is there any good source to learn about it?

Comment: To learn about Bayesian statistics? Yes. I recommend Peter Hoff's First Course in Bayesian Statistical Methods.

Comment: You can see this [article](http://www.marketingdistillery.com/2014/09/24/bayesian-modeling-of-click-through-rate-for-small-data/) to get some ideas